# Laravel 8: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project, and in this project, I have made this method to return **latest** data from the DB, limiting 5 results:

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Blog::all()->latest()->limit(5);;
        return view('blog', compact('posts'));
    }
```

As you can see I have used `latest()` because, I'm using Laravel timestamps (created_at, updated_at) and as [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-can-i-get-the-latest-record-in-database-based-on-datetime) link is saying, there's a handy eloquent/qb method called `->latest()` for showing the latest results.

But now I get this as error:

> BadMethodCallException Method
> **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.**

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Note that I also used `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` at the top of Controller, but didn't solve the problem!

Comment: Spending some time to read up on the Laravel docs really makes a difference knowing what Laravel is capable of and how to properly use the API, to increase coding performance in the future.

Comment: @DanielCheung Yes, I am going to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`latest()` is a `Eloquent\Builder` method. `Blog::all()` is an `Eloquent\Collection` instance.

For your code to work, it should be:

```php
Blog::latest()->limit(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Blog::latest()->simplePaginate(10);
```